# There is no ftp menu in Visual Studio 2022 publish menu. How can I publish via ftp?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ftp, publish

I'm trying to create an app via C# WPF and deploy it as an ftp server.
And this is my development environment.

C#(WPF), Visual Studio Community 2022, .NET 6.0

I went into the properties of the solution as it says on the internet.
And when I go to posting, the ftp menu is not visible.
Is there no way I can distribute the app via ftp?

[image]

Comment: I guess it could be because of payloads not selected during installation; not sure. Try adding ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Wpf application publish list will be as you can see. FTP/FTPS server options will be lost.

You can create an [ASP.NET Core Web App](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet) to check it out.

[image]